# regex - how to select all double slashes except followed by colon

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with RegEx, it may be a basic stuff but I cannot find a correct way how to do it. Please help!

So, here's my question:

I have a list of URLs, that are invalid because of double slash, like this:
`http://website.com//wp-content/folder/file.jpg`, to fix it I need to remove all double slashes except the first one followed by colon (`http://`), so fixed URL is this: `http://website.com/wp-content/folder/file.jpg`.

I need to do it with RegExp.

**Variant 1**

`url.replace(/\/\//g,'/'); // => http:/website.com/wp-content/folder/file.jpg`

will replace all double slashed (`//`), including the first one, which is not correct.

---

example here: 
https://regex101.com/r/NhCVMz/2

Comment: *"I need to do it with RegExp"*: I'm afraid each time I read this. For what reason you need to do it using a regex?

Comment: Are you able to to assume that no URL in the list has a '?' or '#' character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
url = url.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/){2,}/g, "$1$2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhCVMz/3)

Note: a `^` anchor at the beginning of the pattern might be used if the strings are entire URLs.

This pattern will match and capture `http://` or `https://` and will restore it in the resulting string with the `$1` backreference and all other cases of 2 or more `/` will be matched by `(\/){2,}` and only 1 occurrence will be put back into the resulting string since the capturing group does not include the quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

Find `(^|[^:])/{2,}`
Replace `$1/`

delimited:  `/(^|[^:])\/{2,}/`